# Site icons are squashed in the newsletters page in the Firefox browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox, newsletter

In the [**Edit Profile & Settings** -> **Newsletters**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/newsletters/current) tab (under EMAIL SETTINGS), the site icons look squashed in Firefox.

When inspecting the element for the div, the following CSS class caused the display issue:

```
.grid {
    display: flex;
}
```

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Newsletter icon]

**Configuration:**

OS: Windows 7 
Mozilla Firefox: 58.0.2 (64-bit) 
Zoom: 100%

Comment: Works fine in Chrome though.

Comment: @älёxölüt Yes, I have raised the bug for the Firefox browser only.

Comment: perhaps it should be reflected in the title for more obviousness

Comment: @älёxölüt Agree, I have updated the title with browser name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon squash issue has been fixed recently.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Icon Squash issue]

I can verify in Mozilla Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit).